# return all data in a mysql table with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to return all information on the offers table.

```
$sth = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * from offers');
$sth->execute();
$resultex = $sth->fetch();
$sth->close();
return json_encode($resultex);
```

But this doesn't work. How do I do that with prepared statement in `mysqli`?

I do not want to use PDO in this case.

Comment: define: `this not work`, I see you're using `return` while you're not inside a function

Comment: `$resultex` is a boolean return value, not an array.  `mysqli_statement::fetch` does not work similarly to `mysqli_fetch_*()`. You will first need to call `$sth->bind_result()` to bind variables for output. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` and friends return a single row of the result set.   Also, `fetch` uses bind variables, so you need a different scheme for obtaining your results. `get_result` and `fetch_array` will most likely work for you.

You need to loop over the rows, something like this:

```
$sth->execute();
while ($row = $sth->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        foreach ($row as $r)
        {
            /* do your json encoding for the present row */
        }
    }
$sth->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bind your results to variables.  See the documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).  You'll need to do something like this:

```
/* bind result variables */
$sth->bind_result($var1, $var2, $var3);

while ($sth->fetch()) {
    $intermediateVariable[] = array($var1, $var2, $var3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's set this straight, a few things:

### You don't need to use a prepared statement in this case!

Prepared statements are great when you have *parameters*. The golden rule: If you have variables in your query (even if they're constant, mind you), you need prepared statements. If you don't have them, **you don't need prepared statements**.

### You want all of the information, but you only fetch once

`mysqli_statement::fetch()` will only fetch one row. If you want more, you need to use a `while` loop.

### You are `return`ing but it doesn't look like you're in a function

Are you? `return` doesn't output anything. So outside of a function/method scope, you won't get anything out of `return` in that context.